# Исключения С++ деление на ноль

Tags: c++, исключения

Дошел до темы исключения в С++. Такой вопрос, как задать исключение деление на 0? 
Если инструкция не работает

```
try{ 4/0; } catch(...) { cout << "BAD"; };
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это *разные* исключения - аппаратные и программные.

Вы можете, например, сделать так:

```
try
{
    if (c==0) throw std::exception("Деление на 0");
    a = b/c;
} catch(std::exception&e)
{
    cout << e.what();
}
```

В принципе, в VC++ можно заставить аппаратные исключения генерировать программные исключения C++, но это не рекомендуемый скользкий путь... (См., например, [тут](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/swezty51.aspx)).

Answer (score 2):

Деление на 0 в C++ [есть undefined behaviour](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.mul#4). То есть делить на ноль просто нельзя. Никакого исключения при этом стандарт не обещает (а обещает, наоборот, проблемы).